# Plot Numerical range of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, ellipse

How can i plot the numerical range of a hermitian matrix in R?
For example i have the following matrix:

```
a = matrix(c(8+5i,6,0,14+5i),2,2,byrow = T)
a
eigen(a)
```

The numerical range is an ellipse with foci the eigenvalues of the matrix 
For example.

```
qplot(Re(c(14,8)), Im(c(5i,5i)), geom="point")
```

But how can i draw the ellipse in R.
I tried this one but fails:

```
ellipseFun <- function(center = c(0,0),axis = c(0,0), npoints = 100){
  phi =  pi/3
  tt  =  seq(0,2*pi,length.out = npoints)
  xx  =  center[1] + axis[1]*cos(t)*cos(phi) - axis[2]*sin(t)*sin(phi)
  yy  =  center[2] + axis[1]*cos(t)*cos(phi) + axis[2]*sin(t)*cos(phi)
  return(data.frame(x = xx, y = yy))
}
dat <- ellipseFun(c(14,8),c(20,20),npoints = 100)
head(dat)
dat1 = data.frame(x=c(14,8),y=c(0,0));dat1
p = ggplot (dat1, aes (x = x, y = y))+
  geom_point()
p
p+geom_path(data=dat)
```

Comment: I get `Error in cos(t) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function` when trying to evaluate `dat <- ellipseFun(c(14,8),c(20,20),npoints = 100)`. Did you mean `tt`?

Comment: Yes.Probably yes